# Parsing JSON file with multiple arrays using Python

Tags: python, json

I tried to retrieve the data from JSON file and assign them into object type like code the below. The data has multiple arrays in order with lat and lng. Using **Python** how could I deal with this one?

**Current Python code***

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, abort, url_for, json
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

...
with open('./data/file.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    features = json.loads(data)['features']
    for o in features:
        print(o['coordinates'])). <----'Data from JSON file'
...
app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

**Orginal JSON file**

```
{
    "features": [{
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -79.3998992207101,
                    43.770625433748776
                ],
                [
                    -79.39977945240246,
                    43.770651091617324
                ],
                [
                    -79.39970177723474,
                    43.77046066096583
                ],
                [
                    -79.39982154480901,
                    43.77043500133246
                ],
                [
                    -79.3998992207101,
                    43.770625433748776
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }]
}
```

**Data from JSON file**

```
[[[-79.3998992207101, 43.770625433748776], [-79.39977945240246, 43.770651091617324], [-79.39970177723474, 43.77046066096583], [-79.39982154480901, 43.77043500133246], [-79.3998992207101, 43.770625433748776]]]
```

**Result I am aiming at**

```
var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: -79.3998992207101, lng: 43.770625433748776},
    {lat: -79.39977945240246, lng: 43.770651091617324},
    {lat: -79.39970177723474, lng: 43.77042949785241},
    {lat: -79.39987169202237, lng: 43.77039053223808}
    .....
  ];
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for your comment. I edited the post. Could you check it again?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: You access `features` immediate, but there's nothing like that in your file.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry to make you confused. I posted the original JSON file as well.

Comment: And now: what have you tried to solve the actual problem?

Comment: @KlausD.After retrieving the data from JSON file, I assign each array into the object, then each object is added to an array-like 'Result I am aiming at' in the post.

Comment: @Flames JSON is invalid.

Comment: @VishalSingh Thank you for your reply. Well, I grab some of the contents from the original JSON file. Now It would be valid as I updated the post.

Comment: it's still invalid. validate your JSON at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @VishalSingh Sorry. There's some mistake. Could you check it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this really easy function, just replace `print(o['coordinates']))` with function name as I show in example

```
def unpack_coordinates(coordinates):
    coordinates_list = list()
    for item in coordinates[0]:
        coordinates_list.append({"lat": item[0], "lng": item[1]})
    return coordinates_list

# Your Flask code
...
with open('JSON.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    features = json.loads(data)["features"]
    for o in features:
        print(unpack_coordinates(o["coordinates"]))
...
```

Output

```
[
    {'lat': -79.3998992207101, 'lng': 43.770625433748776}, 
    {'lat': -79.39977945240246, 'lng': 43.770651091617324}, 
    {'lat': -79.39970177723474, 'lng': 43.77046066096583}, 
    {'lat': -79.39982154480901, 'lng': 43.77043500133246}, 
    {'lat': -79.3998992207101, 'lng': 43.770625433748776}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep only original json file in context here

```
In [87]: a = json.laod(open("./data/file.json"))
In [88]: triangleCoords = []

In [89]:  for i in a["features"]:
    ...:     for j in i["coordinates"][0]:
    ...:        triangleCoords.append({"lat":j[0],"lng":j[1]})
    ...:

In [90]: triangleCoords
Out[90]:
[{'lat': -79.3998992207101, 'lng': 43.770625433748776},
 {'lat': -79.39977945240246, 'lng': 43.770651091617324},
 {'lat': -79.39970177723474, 'lng': 43.77046066096583},
 {'lat': -79.39982154480901, 'lng': 43.77043500133246},
 {'lat': -79.3998992207101, 'lng': 43.770625433748776}]
```

Answer (score 0):

depending upon how you truncated you JSON there is a possibility of making it less nested.

```
import json

with open('./data/file.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    features = json.loads(data)["features"]
    triangleCoords = []
    for o in features:
        for key, values in o.items():
            for value in values:
                for v in value:
                    triangleCoords.append({"lat": v[0], "lng": v[1]})

print(triangleCoords)
```

Output:

```
[
    {"lat": -79.3998992207101, "lng": 43.770625433748776},
    {"lat": -79.39977945240246, "lng": 43.770651091617324},
    {"lat": -79.39970177723474, "lng": 43.77046066096583},
    {"lat": -79.39982154480901, "lng": 43.77043500133246},
    {"lat": -79.3998992207101, "lng": 43.770625433748776},
]
```